# Can't display what is held in State property, but can display what I add to it - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Please find my code at [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj8pj7pm1o)

I am writing a simple todo list (basically crud) on my own after watching a tutorial, so that I can get to grips with React properly.

After playing around with the code, I eventually had it where the pre-populated list of tasks were being displayed - but I could not add anything to the list.

Now however, I can add things to the list (which is good) - but I can't seem to display the pre-populated items within the list (which is bad).

I feel that my main culprit is the following, but I'm not sure what is going on:

**ListBody**

```
displayTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task, index) =>
      <ListItem key={index} {...task} />
    );
  }

  listTasks() {
    console.log(this.props.tasks);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.listTasks.bind(this)}>list</button>
        {this.displayTasks()}

      </div>
    )
  }
```

**ListItem**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.task}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Update**

After some further investigation - I was creating an edit/delete button for each entry - To which I found that the 3 pre-populated tasks in my list actually displayed the buttons, but not the text of the task itself...

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you add the `task` and what the initial output of `console.log(this.props.tasks)` is?

Comment: @DavinTryon - This was solved below by xjmdoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make your example code work with a few modifications:

```
//list-item.js
class ListItem extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.task.name}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//list-body.js
class ListBody extends React.Component {

  displayTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task, index) =>
      <ListItem key={index} task={task} />
    );
  }

//app.js
createTask(task) {
    console.log('Creating task...');
    console.log(task);

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState.tasks.push({ name: task, isComplete: false });
      return {
        tasks: prevState.tasks
      }
    })

    this.printTasks();

}
```

Here is the working demo: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/1z7x9z9j03)

Comment: Aha! Life saver. @xjmdoo - not sure what was really missing in the end, but it seems to have worked. I had tried to use the (prevState) way previously but didn't quite have it right - I think it was because I hadn't returned the prevState.tasks as you had.

Answer (score 1):

You are spreading all the `task` properties onto `ListItem` when it looks like you want to just set a `task` prop.  Try this instead:

```
<ListItem key={index} task={task} />
```

Comment: Using task={task} gives an Invariant Violation "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, isComplete}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.".
I tried task={this.task} also, but with no success :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = this 

 <ListItem key={index}  onClick={that.listTasks.bind(task)  />
```

Comment: It definitely didn't like that.
See my question for an update on my investigation